# Ruby PrettyPrint in single quote

Tags: ruby, pretty-print

how to make Ruby `pp` function outputing String in valid (parsable) Ruby string using single quote if possible?

```
rows = [{name:'test',id:'182572'},{name:"Kal'el",id:'125125'}]
require 'pp'
pp rows
```

output was:

```
[{:name=>"test", :id=>"182572"}, {:name=>"Kal'el", :id=>"125125"}]
```

desired output was:

```
[{:name=>'test', :id=>'182572'}, {:name=>"Kal'el", :id=>'125125'}]
```

(is it possible to use quote single quote inside single quote string?)

nevermind, i found the answer since my edit on sawa's answer has been rejected, i'll put it here:

```
class String
  alias :old_inspect :inspect
  def inspect
    return old_inspect if self.include? "'"
    "'#{self}'"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Strings, after parsing, aren't double or single quoted, they're just strings. If you want strings to appear with single quotes, you'll have to write your own printing function.

Answer (score 1):

Redefine `String#inspect`.

```
class String
  def inspect; "'#{self}'" end
end
```

Comment: don't forget to change it back afterwards, or ALL strings will wind up with double quotes in range of the program~

Comment: @Kokizzu What do you mean by incorrect? You need to make that clear.

Comment: @Kokizzu I don't understand what you mean by incorrect. Therefore I do not understand what you mean by you think you understand how to use it (although I know what your code would do). You have not made it clear yet.

Comment: it quoting incorrectly (not a valid Ruby string) when there are single quote inside the string..

Comment: @Kokizzu Indeed it is not a valid Ruby string. And how is it incorrect? What is the relevance of a valid Ruby string to your question?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you actually need this to be executable Ruby? If so, you should ask about that, because using `pp` is probably not the best way of generating code.

Comment: i'm trying to generate back data from database to a ruby code.. but when using `pp` all i got was double quoted string, and i want to follow the ruby style guide that is `Prefer single-quoted strings when you don't need string interpolation or special symbols`


ref: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#strings